# How to handle exception for java.lang.IllegalStateException when server throw exception for http-listener max-parameters limit cross on wildfly

Tags: java, struts2, wildfly

2019-03-03 13:53:01,193 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-79) UT005023: Exception handling request to *********.action: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000047: The number of parameters exceeded the maximum of 1000
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormData.add(FormData.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormData.add(FormData.java:68)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormEncodedDataDefinition$FormEncodedDataParser.doParse(FormEncodedDataDefinition.java:172)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormEncodedDataDefinition$FormEncodedDataParser.parseBlocking(FormEncodedDataDefinition.java:251)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.parseFormData(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:762)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getParameterMap(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.createContextMap(Dispatcher.java:592)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.PrepareOperations.createActionContext(PrepareOperations.java:78)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.ha

Comment: Try sending a single param of json rather than over 1000 parameters

Comment: Thank You so much @will.  You gave me some hint. 
I was passing my row ids as an array of string, and the parameter size increase as selected record increase. 
Now, I converted my array of rowids into a string which makes it as a single parameter. 
My issue solved. Now, I can update any number of records without any restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following CLI Command to increase the max-parameter values:
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default/:write-attribute(name=max-parameters,value=5000)

or

Add max-parameters="5000" in standalone.xml and restart server

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.2">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-parameters="5000"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
```